# How can I change the validations based on previous field input angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have two fields in reactive form in angular. I need to validate second field and show error message based on first field option chosen.

*Field one:*

```
<label>ID proof </b><span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
     <mat-select name="idproofs" placeholder="IDProof name" required formControlName="idProof" class="form-control">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let idproof of idproofs" [value]="idproof.value">
        {{idproof.viewValue}}
     </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

*Field two:*

```
<label>ID proof number </b><span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
       <input matInput placeholder="ID Proof Number" required formControlName="idFroofNumber" class="form-control">
    <mat-error *ngIf="PGroup.controls['idProofNumber'].hasError('required')">
       ID proof number is required!
    </mat-error>
   </mat-form-field>
```

**Example** in first field if I choose option as **Adhaar number** then in second field the validation must be only number with 12 digit characters max length.

If I choose **PAN number** then only validation will be alphanumeric with 10 characters max length. And accordingly if I can give error message validation as well. How I can achieve that

**EDIT** added ts formcontrol

```
this.PGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      idProof: ['', Validators.required],
      idProofNumber: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[\w\s]+$/)]]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide your ts code? I see you use ngModel combined with formControlName, and I think that it's combined reactive approach with template driven approach.
Anyway, here my advice.
Use reactive approach in this way, (only suggestion, you could get the idea and implement base on your preference)

```
// attr declarations
fieldOne = new FormControl('',[]); // initial value and validators inside array
fieldTwo = new FormControl('', []); // initialValue and validators

// ngOnInit
fieldOne.valueChanges.
.pipe(
debounceTime(100),   // dalay after every change to update your validations
distinctUntilChanged(), // only update validators when value change
tap(value => {

// depend on your options you can use switch here
   if(value === 'Adhaar number'){
    this.fieldTwo.setValidators([Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(12)]);
    this.fieldTwo.updateValueAndValidity();
  } else 
 if(value === 'PAN number'){
    this.fieldTwo.setValidators([Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(10)]);
    this.fieldTwo.updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
this.fieldTwo.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    this.fieldTwo.updateValueAndValidity();
}
})

)
.subscribe()
```

Update your html base on your possible errors .

Also you can use formGroup with two field instead of separated formControls, and only change subscription from this.fieldOne.valueChanges to this.form.get('fieldOne').valueChanges

Remember to unsubscribe from this subscription. I suggest https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/until-destroy

Comment: ok, in that case update my code using this.PGroup.get('yourField') base on subscription or update validators

Comment: I am not using ngModel it was before I forgot to remove it. I am using reactive forms only. And I am updating my question in EDIT  providing ts file controllers. I am using group only. So can you modify according to group which I have added according to you have suggested ?

Comment: `Validators.maxLength()` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this,

Lets say you have component with the name AppComponent,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl, 
  ValidationErrors, 
  AbstractControl, 
  ValidatorFn 
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'stackoverflow-examples';
    panelOpenState = false;
    idproofOptions: string[] = ['Aadhar','PAN'];
    idproofsForm: FormGroup;

    get idproofsFormControl(): FormControl {
      // debugger
      return this.idproofsForm.controls['idproofs'] as FormControl;
    }

    get idproofsInputFormControl(): FormControl {
      // debugger
      return this.idproofsForm.controls['idproofsInput'] as FormControl;
    }

    idproofInputAadharValidation(): ValidatorFn {
      return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        // debugger
        const pattern = new RegExp("^[0-9]{10}$");
        if (pattern.test(control.value)) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return {
            aadharError: 'Aadhar number is not correct'
          };
        }
      };
    }

    idproofInputPANValidation(): ValidatorFn {
      return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        // debugger
        const pattern = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        if (pattern.test(control.value)) {
          return null;
        } else {
          return {
            panError: 'PAN number is not correct'
          };
        }
      };
    }

    constructor(
      private fb: FormBuilder
    ) { 
      this.idproofsForm = new FormGroup(
        {
          idproofs: new FormControl(''),
          idproofsInput: new FormControl('')
        }
      );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.idproofsForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
        field => {
          // debugger
          console.log(this.idproofsForm.controls['idproofsInput']);
          if (field['idproofs'] && field['idproofs'] === 'PAN') {
            this.idproofsInputFormControl.clearValidators();
            this.idproofsInputFormControl.setValidators(this.idproofInputPANValidation());
          } else if (field['idproofs'] && field['idproofs'] === 'Aadhar') {
            this.idproofsInputFormControl.clearValidators();
            this.idproofsInputFormControl.setValidators(this.idproofInputAadharValidation());
          }
          // debugger
        }
      );
    }

}
```

Your HTML can look like this,

```
<label>ID proof<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-select [formControl]="idproofsFormControl" name="idproofs" placeholder="IDProof name" required class="form-control">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let idproof of idproofOptions" [value]="idproof">
      {{idproof}}
    </mat-option> 
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<br/>
<!-- {{idproofsInputFormControl|json}} -->
<label>ID proof number<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput placeholder="ID Proof Number" required [formControl]="idproofsInputFormControl" class="form-control">
  <mat-error *ngIf="idproofsInputFormControl.errors">
      {{idproofsInputFormControl.errors['aadharError']}}
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

look at the error below in screenshot
[image]

Note: My suggestion is that you don't use ngModel the reactive approach is far better, you may have to change this code a little to fit your requirement but I am sure it should be helpful

Comment: I am not using ngModel. I forgot to remove that from code. Although I will give a try of yours but where is the validation for Adhaar ? Adhaar consist of only numeric. Same if I add driving license or voter card tomorrow then those will be alphanumeric again. In that case ?

Comment: see these two validation funtions `idproofInputAadharValidation ` and `idproofInputPANValidation ` also note that this code is just the indication as how you can achieve your desired answer may not be completely fitting your bill

Comment: Understood. Thanks I will give a try

Comment: just a detail, if you subscribe to all changes of entire form, take care of that approach, because every time you change idproofsInput field, you will also execute that subscripcion, I think you should evaluate modify this solution to subscribe only to  idProof changes

Comment: yeh correct, but as i have mentioned it needs a lil modification to fit exact requirement however this is very close to what @OptimistRohit
 needs

Comment: @DeepakJha How can I give min max length validation over here ?

Comment: @DeepakJha Also, I have added EDIT 2 according to your solution and according to my form group. It is not working. Can you check what am I missing ?

Comment: use regex for max length or provide in formControl, can you give me your repo link? Just the read access, may be?